# How to reduce negative exponents (mod $p$), when applying Fermat's Little Theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble solving a Fermat's Little Theorem problem

I have $(2^{19808} + 6)^{-1} + 1 \bmod 11$.

My attempt is $((2^{10})^{1980}2^8 + 6)^{-1} + 1 \bmod 11$

So my final answer is $1/262 + 1 \bmod 11$, which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: In modular arithmetic, we tend to write $m^{-1}$, not $1/n$ because we are not talking about fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$19808\equiv8\pmod{10}$

$\implies2^{19808}\equiv2^8\equiv3\pmod{11}$

$\implies(2^{19808}+6)^{-1}\equiv9^{-1}\equiv5\pmod{11}$ as $9\cdot5\equiv1\pmod{11}$

Comment: In your third step, where is the + 1? do we just ignore it?

Comment: @user270494,  $a\equiv b\pmod m\iff a+1\equiv b+1$

Comment: @user270494 You're expected to finish it.Add 1.